# Does Java's SocketChannel$read() synchronize the output buffer?

Tags: java, networking, nio, synchronized, channel

Does Java's SocketChannel.read() method synchronize the output buffer?

In other words: is there a lock on the ByteBuffer argument passed to the `read(ByteBuffer)` method in java.nio.channels.SocketChannel (basically any channel). I need to know this so I don't have unnecessary synchronization blocks.

Comment: Why don't you look in the [source code](http://www.grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7-b147/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.java#SocketChannel.read%28java.nio.ByteBuffer%29)?

Comment: Wait, really? Since when does Oracle publish their source code?

Comment: Since Java has gone open source?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java-Doc for SocketChannel says:

- Socket channels are safe for use by multiple concurrent threads.  They
- support concurrent reading and writing, though at most one thread may be
- reading and at most one thread may be writing at any given time.  The {@link
- #connect connect} and {@link #finishConnect finishConnect} methods are
- mutually synchronized against each other, and an attempt to initiate a read
- or write operation while an invocation of one of these methods is in
- progress will block until that invocation is complete.